# Why do we use negative sign for electric potential/voltage?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, voltage, conventions

Negative sign is used for electric potential belonging to negative charge but whenever in electrostatics the "negative" sign is referencing for example: force means its attractive or repulsive. Then electric potential is a scalar quantity why do we need to make it so that we need to specify it as attractive or repulsive? Also when we look at the charge's electric potential at points , we find that its more negative closer to it and less negative far and far why is it so , as electric potential is the ability of the charge to repel or attract the test charge at a certain distance shouldn't it be more positive near it (as more energy).

I find this idea very confusing any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have mixed up two uses for the minus sign.

**Forces**
Suppose charge $q_1$ is separated from charge $q_2$ by a distant $r$.
Let the position of $q_1$ be the origin of a coordinate system with the unit vector $\hat r$ be pointing away from charge $q_2$ so $\vec r = r \hat r$.
In some way or other you find the force $\vec F=F\hat i$ on charge $q_2$ due to charge $q_1$.
If $F$ is positive this tells you that the direction of the force on charge $q_2$ is in the same direction as that of unit vector $\hat r$, ie away from charge $q_1$ - repulsive, whereas $F$ being negative tells you that the direction of the force is $\hat r$, ie towards charge $q_1$ - attractive.

**Potentials**
You quite rightly say that potential is a scalar quantity so how can it be negative implying that the sign has something to do with direction.
Well it does have a direction - on the number line.
Your bank balance is 1000 Razz, which means that have have 1000 Razz more than nothing in the bank.
If your bank balance was is deficit by 500 Razz then you could write that as -500 Razz ie 500 less than nothing in the bank.
For a given situation the origin of a number line can be chosen arbitrarily.
Think of the heights of mountains which are measured relative to *sea level*, the height of a pendulum bob above a laboratory bench when the bob is below the level of the bench.
Potential is measured on a number line with the origin chosen arbitrarily.

*Negative sign is used for electric potential belonging to negative charge . . . . .* is because of an arbitrarily but generally accepted convention.
The potential at a point is the work done in moving unit **positive** charge from a given zero of potential (the origin of the number line) to that point.
Moving a unit positive charge towards a negative charge requires no work to be done by an external force and as such we label it negative work and give it a negative sign.
In banking terms moving the unit positive charge towards a negative charge is equivalent to taking money (energy in the case of charge) out of a bank leaving the bank (system of charges) with less money (electric potential energy).

Comment: Yeah, this is the fundamental confusion of the OP. Take my upvote.

Comment: Thank you for the answer , and nice name for the currency :)

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $V(x)=x^2$ in 1D. Sketch it right now. It is a U-shaped potential. Imagine you have a physical U-shaped track, and you place a marble and let go (under our everyday influence of gravity… but my discussion is not really about gravity; this is just a visualization experiment). WHat’s going to happen? If you started your marble at some point with $x$-coordinate $x_0>0$ (i.e you start at the point $(x_0,V(x_0))=(x_0,x_0^2)$ on the graph to the right of the minimum) then it is going to fall to the left, trying to go down to the minimum.

If you started on the left, i.e $(x_0,x_0^2)$ with $x_0<0$, then the marble will fall again to the minimum, which is now on the right. So, we make the following observations

- if we’re on the right, i.e if $x>0$, we want the force to be pushing us towards the origin which is to the left
- if we’re on the left, i.e if $x<0$, we want the force to push us to the origin which is to the right.

Now, forces are described by the changes in potential energy (derivative), and in our case, $V’(x)=2x$. Notice that if $x>0$, then $V’(x)=2x>0$, meaning if you start on the right, then having a force equal to $V’$ would push you to the right, **which is opposite of our first bullet point**. Similarly, if we have $x<0$, then $V’(x)=2x<0$, so having a force equal to $V’$ would push us to the left, which again is **opposite to our second bullet point**.

If on the other hand we have $F=-V’$, with the minus sign, then $F’(x)=-2x$, and all the directions work out correctly.

---

Note, that you can now very meaningfully ask me why not just start with the function $W(x)=-x^2$, so an inverted parabola, and call this our potential, and then define $F(x)=W’(x)=-2x$, so we don’t have any excess minus signs in the formula $F=W’$? Well, you certainly could, and I personally don’t have any issues with it, and there is no mathematical issues with it, there are no physical issues either, since the math models the physics just the same either way, and if you did things this way, then after an initial knee-jerk reaction, people would understand you just fine. The only thing is now if you place a marble to the right (i.e $x>0$), then having the force $F’(x)=W’(x)=-2x<0$ would mean the particle would have to go up the potential… which just sounds weird, and people don’t like this. We always like things to go downhill :)

Now although I talked about marbles (which alludes to Newtonian gravity), it’s not restricted to that. You can play similar analogies with Coulomb’s law, and it’s exactly the same reason why we put that extra minus sign.

It’s just a convention. I personally don’t like this convention for some purposes, but for others, it comes out nicely (e.g $-\nabla^2$ is a ‘positive operator’ in the sense that $\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}(\nabla^2 f)\cdot f=\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}|\nabla f|^2\geq 0$ for nice functions $f$… though you may not find this a compelling reason right now).

Answer (score 2):

Electric Potential at a point itself is actually not a meaningful quantity, it is only meaningful when we have two points to compare with, and then we can talk about the electric potential of a point relative to another. For example, we can define a point's potential relative to infinity, like we talk about gravitational potential relative to the ground.

So imagine there is a positive charge, and we bring another positive charge closer to it. As we do work on it, the change in potential energy is positive, and it is now at a higher potential relative to its original point. Vice versa, if we want to bring a negative charge to the same place from the same point, we do not do any work on it, and the negative charge goes to that point by itself under the influence of the electric field. It is now therefore at a lower potential than its original point.

Now we take that original point as potential equals zero, like how we take the ground to have zero gravitational potential (it is arbitrary). The potential of the positive charge now is greater than zero, thus positive, and the negative charge is smaller than zero, thus negative.

Therefore, by knowing the sign of the potential at the final position, we know how the charges will behave. Both charges will move towards the original position in this case. The only complication you need to look out for, is that in gravity, everything moves from higher potential to lower potential, but in charges, positive charges move from high potential to low potential whereas negative charges move from low potential to high potential.

In conclusion, the sign of the potential gives us an idea of how the charge will move relative to another point.